# How to update devexpress gridview data column value automatically if condition is met?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I need to update devexpress gridview data column value automatically if condition is met. I tried to implement it using HtmldatacellPrepared
but there is error at line e.GetValue("Status") =  "Delay" : Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment. Is there any other method to use to implement this?

```
Protected Sub Grid_HtmldatacellPrepared(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs)
if e.GetValue("Forecast") IsNot DBNull.Value Then

  If e.DataColumn.VisibleIndex = 9 Then

     If e.GetValue("Forecast") > Date.Now Then

         e.GetValue("Status") = "Delay"        

     End if

  End If

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **ASPxGridView.CustomColumnDisplayText** event instead of the **ASPxGridView.HtmlDataCellPrepared** one, and set the EventArgs e.DisplayText property. Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484929).

Answer (score 1):

`e.GetValue("...")` is a function so you cannot assign value to it.

I don't have DevExpress component handy to test but based on their online doc, I draft below how to set the cell value.

In order to set the value of the `"Status"` cell, handle the grid's `CustomColumnDisplayText` event. Detect if the target cell (i.e `"Status"`) is currently being processed and set the value using `e.DisplayText` property.

```
Protected Sub ASPxGridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs) Handles ASPxGridView1.CustomColumnDisplayText
    If e.Column.FieldName = "Status" Then
        Dim grid = DirectCast(sender, ASPxGridView)
        Dim forecast As Object = grid.GetRowValues(e.VisibleRowIndex,"Forecast")

        If forecast IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso CDate(forecast) > Date.Now Then
            e.DisplayText = "Delay"
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Hopefully that will give you rough idea.